# CSS Not Showing Up in Django with NGINX and uWSGI

Tags: python, css, django, nginx, uwsgi

This is my first real Django project and I am trying to configure it for production using NGINX and uWSGI. It is running on a Digital Ocean Ubuntu server. Everything is set up and working besides serving static CSS files. The strange thing about this is that its serving static images and JavaScript files fine, the only thing that isn't being served is the CSS.

This is what my site configuration file for NGINX looks like ('nebula' is the Ubuntu User and the name of the Django project):

```
# configuration of the server
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    charset     utf-8;
    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;
    # Django media and static files
    location /media  {
        alias /home/nebula/nebula/media;
    }
    location /assets {
        alias /home/nebula/nebula/assets;
    }
    # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/nebula/nebula/uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

This is what my Settings.py file looks like:

```py
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

STATIC_URL = '/assets/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/")

STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets/'),)
```

This is what my base directory looks like (assets and static are the same, I duplicated it in an attempt to solve the issue):

```
assets      demo.py    media   nebula.sock       static  uwsgi_params
db.sqlite3  manage.py  nebula  nebula_uwsgi.ini  set     store
```

This is inside of 'assets/':

```
admin  css  images  jazzmin  js  vendor
```

Answer (score 0):

The location path for your static files in your nginx config should match your `STATIC_URL` setting

```
    location /assets {
        alias /home/nebula/nebula/assets;
    }
```

Comment: For some reason that made more images render but the CSS still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there could be an issue here

Could you try Changing

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media/'),)
```

to

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets/'),)
```

Comment: I changed it but now when I run 'python manage.py collectstatic' it throws this error: 'The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.'

Comment: Can you try 
```
STATIC_URL = "/assets/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "assets/"),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/assets/") 
```

Comment: After adding those suggestions it throws "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/assets'" when I run 'python manage.py collectstatic'.

Comment: That's a permission issue,
https://fedingo.com/how-to-fix-errno-13-permission-denied-error-in-django/#:~:text=Sometimes%20you%20may%20get%20%E2%80%9CErrno,folders%20used%20by%20the%20request.

Follow this to solve that